# Python wrapper script to let a program be executed remotely with no blocking

Tags: python, fork

I am looking for a wrapper script to run a program which is called remotely by a SSH command which terminates without waiting for the result of the program.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os, subprocess

def main():
   print "PID_last_child", os.getpid()
   argpass = ['main_p.py']
   for a in sys.argv:
        if a.find("wrapper.py") == -1: 
            argpass.append(a)
   pid = subprocess.Popen(argpass).pid
   print "PID for the actual process: ", pid


if __name__ == "__main__":

  print "PID_MAIN:", os.getpid()

  try: 
         pid = os.fork() 
         print "FORK1: ", pid 
         if pid > 0: 
               sys.exit(0)
   except OSError, e:  
         print >>sys.stderr, "fork failed: %d (%s)" % (e.errno, e.strerror)
         sys.exit(1)

   os.chdir('/') 
   os.setsid()
   os.umask(0) 

   try:
         pid = os.fork() 
         print "FORK2: ", pid 
         if pid > 0: 
                sys.exit(0)
   except OSError, e:  
         print >>sys.stderr, "fork failed: %d (%s)" % (e.errno, e.strerror)
         sys.exit(1)

   main()
```

I suppose using double forking, i should be able to do that... but no luck so far.

Any thoughts on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you use an `&` in your shell script?

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect. Could you check it again?

Comment: not really... I'd rather handle it with a wrapper script...

Comment: well, I just realized that I have no control over ssh part now... so basically no I cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fully credit this link for the answer in bash syntax: [How to starting process as daemon using ssh command?](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/70523-how-starting-process-daemon-using-ssh-command.html)

You don't even need to double-fork. The issue is that the stdout is still connected. Here is the python approach:

**wrapper.py**

```
import subprocess
import os

def main():
    pid = subprocess.Popen(['nohup', '/path/to/main_p.py'], 
                            stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w+', 0),
                            stderr = subprocess.STDOUT
                            ).pid
    print pid

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

And then the ssh command would call this wrapper:

```
ssh server /path/to/wrapper.py
```

You just need to redirect stdout -> devull, and the process will return right away.

Comment: @AmirReza: This is in the script being called by the ssh command, not int the ssh command itself. Your ssh command executes this which launches your actual process.

Comment: What I meant is, I do not have "2>&1 &" in my ssh line.

The ssh line is "ssh server wrapper.py"

Comment: @AmirReza: You are not listening to what I am saying. Your ssh command does exactly what you just typed. Inside of your wrapper.py, you call your subprocess command launches with stdout redirected to dev null. You do not need to do anything different to how the ssh command calls the script.

Comment: Works for me when I test it via ssh. Without it, it blocks until the process is complete. When I use this method, the ssh call returns immediately and the process still runs.

Comment: this is my exact ssh command: ssh -p 22 -i id_dsafile -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=30 -o ConnectionAttempts=2 -o BatchMode=yes -C root@server "wrapper.py x"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14376/discussion-between-amir-reza-and-jdi)

Comment: And you tested this with `wrapper.py` being my exactly example right?